# How to add header and footer without scroll bar on the part of a website?

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar

How can I sticky the header and footer like in this extension on this HTML? 
[Honey Extension Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPlcH.png)
And only scroll the content between the header and footer. 
In this project I use Materialize CSS framework can I do this in this framework?

```
    <header>
        <div class="section"></div>
        <h4 class="center-align">text1</h4>
        <div class="section"></div>
    </header>
    <div id="frequency" class="col s12">
        <table class="highlight">
            <thead>
                <tr class="teal lighten-2">
                    <th class="center-align">text1</th>
                    <th class="center-align">text1</th>
                    <th class="center-align">text1</th>
                    <th class="center-align">tex1</br>(text1)</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="frequencyTable">
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <footer>
            <div class="section"></div>
            <div class="center-align row">
                <a class="col s12 waves-effect waves-light btn-large tooltipped" data-position="top" data-tooltip="Zapisz zmiany">Zapisz</a>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try a structure like this:

```css
* { margin: 0; padding:0; }

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#frequency {
  background-color: orange;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}

footer {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
    <header>
        <div class="section"></div>
        <h4 class="center-align">text1</h4>
        <div class="section"></div>
    </header>
    <div id="frequency" class="col s12">
        <table class="highlight">
            <thead>
                <tr class="teal lighten-2">
                    <th class="center-align">text1</th>
                    <th class="center-align">text1</th>
                    <th class="center-align">text1</th>
                    <th class="center-align">tex1</br>(text1)</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="frequencyTable">
            <tr>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolt.</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolt.</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolt.</td>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolt.</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <footer>
            <div class="section"></div>
            <div class="center-align row">
                <a class="col s12 waves-effect waves-light btn-large tooltipped" data-position="top" data-tooltip="Zapisz zmiany">Zapisz</a>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </div>
```

Comment: I must make some changes but your solution work like i want in my case :D thx bro

Answer (score 2):

Misunderstood the question the first time around here is the working snippet for what you require

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header,
.footer {
  background: silver;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  background: pink;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  /* Remove scrollbar space */
  background: transparent;
  /* Optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="section"></div>
    <h4 class="center-align">text1</h4>
    <div class="section"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div style="height:1000px;">
      <div id="frequency" class="col s12">
        <table class="highlight">
          <thead>
            <tr class="teal lighten-2">
              <th class="center-align">text1</th>
              <th class="center-align">text1</th>
              <th class="center-align">text1</th>
              <th class="center-align">tex1</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="frequencyTable">
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="center-align row">
      <a class="col s12 waves-effect waves-light btn-large tooltipped" data-position="top" data-tooltip="Zapisz zmiany">Zapisz</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Note that the hiding of scrollbar would work only on chromium-based browsers.

Comment: this steal looks the same :(

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question, you only want to hide your scrollbar?

Comment: Oh now I understand. So you wanted to sticky header and footer and make the middle part scrollable?

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/wLLNuz3RJPDfA8tz7 my page looks like that and i want to remove scroll bar from header
  <h4 class="center-align">text1</h4>
and stick this to top of my page this same i want to do with my footer 
 <a class="col s12 waves-effect waves-light btn-large tooltipped" data-position="top" data-tooltip="Zapisz zmiany">Zapisz</a>

Comment: yes i want do that :D  i want only scrollbar on middle of my page

Comment: Thx for your solution :D but now page looks like that https://photos.app.goo.gl/9BiSp4J4i9y9TDx97 what i need change to save scrollbar in the middle ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer i my case your solution still work the same maybe this happening because i using materializecss and this framework adding his own classes and properties :(

Comment: No it will work with materialize, you have  to close the frequency class div before you open the footer div. That was an issue in your original HTML. Check it out if it works.Either way glad to help out :)

Answer (score 1):

First you can try taking the `<footer>` out of the `#frequency` div. 
Then add the following css:

```
header {position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; z-index: 1}
footer {position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; z-index: 2}
```